# ChartsJS get value of Data/Dataset Label for Tooltip

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm very new to ChartJS (and JS in general) and couldn't find a fitting answer for my problem anywhere online.

I'm trying to customize the tooltips in my Bubblechart to fit format:

Dataset Label
x.value: X
y.value: X

For x and y values I'm fine. But I can't get the Headline I want.

For the Title I'm curently trying

```
            tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            title: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                    return data.datasets[tooltipItems[0].datasetIndex].label;
                }               
            }               
        }
```

But this returns the entire array of all Labels for every Bubble. I guess this is due to how I populated the Labels.

```
    data = {
 labels: LabelArray,
 datasets: [{
   label: LabelArray,
       data: chartData
   }]};
```

I have labels under data and datasets because it didn't work with labels under datasets.

Any information on how to solve this is highly appreciated!

Sample Data of my Arrays:

```
    chartData: 
    0: Object { x: "2786", y: "12.4", r: "15.32" }
    1: Object { x: "4998", y: "23.7", r: "52.46" }​
    2: Object { x: "719", y: "20.4", r: "6.5" }​ 
    3: Object { x: "3649", y: "15.9", r: "25.73" }

    LabelArray: 
    0: "A"​ 
    1: "B"​ 
    2: "C"​ 
    3: "D"
```

Best regards,
David

Comment: Adding some sampledata

chartData:
0: Object { x: "2786", y: "12.4", r: "15.32" }​
1: Object { x: "4998", y: "23.7", r: "52.46" }​
2: Object { x: "719", y: "20.4", r: "6.5" }​
3: Object { x: "3649", y: "15.9", r: "25.73" }

LabelArray:
0: "A"​
1: "B"​
2: "C"​
3: "D"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the sampleData you posted above this is what you're passing to your tooltip in `data`. The problem is that you're passing an array to `label` when it is supposed to be a string - [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bubble.html#dataset-properties).

```
data = {
    labels: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
    datasets: [
        {
        label: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
        data: [
                { x: "2786", y: "12.4", r: "15.32" }​,
                { x: "4998", y: "23.7", r: "52.46" }​,
                { x: "719", y: "20.4", r: "6.5" }​,
                { x: "3649", y: "15.9", r: "25.73" }
            ]
      }
  ]
};
```

If you're trying to pass multiple data points with different labels then you will need to breakout your `datasets` into an array of objects like so.

```
data = {
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "A",
        data: [{ x: "2786", y: "12.4", r: "15.32" }​]
      },
      {
        label: "B",
        data: [{ x: "4998", y: "23.7", r: "52.46" }​]
      },
      {
        label: "C",
        data: [{ x: "719", y: "20.4", r: "6.5" }​]
      },
      {
        label: "D",
        data: [{ x: "3649", y: "15.9", r: "25.73" }]
      }
  ]
};
```

If you must save your labels to an array then you need to extract which label you need when building your chart data. Something like this should work...

```
dynamicData =[
  { x: "2786", y: "12.4", r: "15.32" }​,
  { x: "4998", y: "23.7", r: "52.46" }​
];
labelArray = ["A","B","C","D"];
parsedData = [];

for(let i = 0; i < dynamicData.length; i++) {
    parsedData.push({
      label: labelArray[i],
      data: [dynamicData[i]]
    });
}

data = {
    datasets: parsedData
};
```

Comment: The goal is to dynamically add the Label of each Dataset in that Datasets Tooltip. The Labels are stored in an Array. Maybe I don't get your answer?

I've added some sampledata to my original Answer. Maybe the format of my Array is not correct?

Comment: Thanks for your reply & update! Is there any way to do that dynamically? Because I can never telle beforehand how many datapoints there will be

Comment: I figured you may ask that, I just updated my answer with how to do that dynamically :)

Comment: I guess I can just loop through my Arrays then and add datasets after creating the chart?

Comment: Modified again to be more clear about that, in order to dynamically build your dataset you will just loop through whatever you get and build the dataset object. I posted a very rough sample but that should work. If the label is part of the dynamic data returned then grab the label from there instead of `labelArray` in my example.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer! I think I'm almost there. The dataset Object seems fine to me - but somehow I don't get it to work. I've created this simplified Fiddle as example https://jsfiddle.net/egpfoy8m/

Comment: Figured out the problem, inside of `dataset` your `data` needs to be an array like so. `data: [dynamicData[i]]` that's my bad, I updated my original answer with that fix.

Comment: @sHooP were you able to give it a try with my last update?

Comment: I've just updated my Widget - it does work perfectly fine now! Thanks at ton! It feels really good when things fall in place :-)